# Building a Chrome-Inspect-Element-like Tool

Tags: java, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am thinking of building an inspecting tool like the Chrome Inspect Element tool, which allows you to hover over html elements and see the html and css behind. However, my version of this tool, will allow me to see the tables and databases the data I just hovered over, came from?
Basically, think of the chrome Inspect Element tool, but instead of showing you the html and css, it will show you the tables and databases where that data you hovered came from.

One idea I had is following:

1. Hover over a piece of data (1 or 2 words at most)
2. Then iterate over all databases (in my case 5 databases) and then
3. Query all tables of all databases until a match for the word I just 
   hovered over is found.
4. Finally, just return and display that database and table information 
   on the screen for the user.

This could be used as an internal tool to help newly hired Software Developers who are not that familiar with the applications they must work on, i.e debugging and building additional features, to quickly figure out what database and table a piece of data they're currently looking at is coming from.

I'm using .NET FRAMEWORK 4 and C-SHARP but JAVA is my main programming language in case any Java expert could suggest a solution in Java.

I am NOT looking for code, but pseudo-code/steps you would suggest to achieve this solution.

Thanks

Comment: This tool sounds pretty cool, but personally I don't see how you would achieve it. HTTP gives you html documents which was built on a server. The way the data was mapped dynamically from the underlying datalayer is completely unknown to you, and should be. There is from the browsers point of view, no link between the data presented, and the datalayer. What you are asking is probably not impossible, but you'd have to provide alot of meta data with the table.

Comment: It is possible, but you should have custom controls. Your approach is really bad because it is performance disaster.

Comment: @Scherling, mybirthname - Thanks so much for your responses. I realize my approach is performance disaster :) but that's all I could think of.                                                                Could I maybe use the routing mechanism in .NET to identify a relationship between URL pages and databases or something like that?                                   Would knowing what page the data is routed to, cut down on the iteration overhead?

Comment: I do something similar in asp.net forms, I'm not that experienced in mvc to tell you how. In asp.net webforms create for an example customTextBoxCnl with properties Field,TableName. When you are adding the customTextBoxCnl you are writing this two properties values. You can use them for masive data bind after that and also for your case. You should have loop in Controls collection and show the correct cnt.Field, cnt.Table when is needed. In this case you don't need to connect to database, but I don't know how to achieve that exactly in mvc.

Comment: @mybirthname, I see I'll look into this suggestion of yours. Another idea a teammate just suggested to me is to use the SQL profiler, which talks to the SQL SERVER to figure out all the queries and stored procedures that were run. I'm still looking for ideas, but so far so good. Thanks all.

Comment: If this is big solution, which doesn't have build this custom controls, this is impossible and stupid. Because you need to rework every control, the effort will be too big. About the sql profiler this sound okay, but in big solution you are taking data for some calculation and after that it is not visible, also how you will map control with data column name. Probably you can try to build custom Html.Helpers with properties Field/Table. This is the only idea which I have.